# DomXpath e foreach. Como ter uma prévia dos elementos capturados?

Tags: php

Estou aprendendo a lidar com `DOMXpath` no `php`. Estava usando `regex` (mas fui desestimulado aqui no stack quando para captura de html). Confesso que para mim não é tão simples e o `DOM` tem seus limites (quando existem espaços nos nomes da tag e também no gerenciamento de erros). Se alguém puder me ajudar com o comando no `php` para obter uma prévia dos elementos capturados e verificar se está tudo certo, agradeceria. Se tiver sugestão para melhorar o código, também é bem vinda.

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Eliminando espaços em branco (caso existam)
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents ('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?certificates=us:pg_13&genres=comedy&groups=top_250'));
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    // Iniciando a partir do elemento raiz
    $grupos = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item mode-advanced']");
    // Criando um array e depois um loop com os elementos a serem capturados (imagem, titulo e link)
    $resultados = array();
    foreach($grupos as $grupo) {
        $i = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='loadlate']//@src", $grupo);
        $t = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item-header']//a/text()", $grupo);
        $l = $xpath->query(".//*[@class='lister-item-header']//a/@href", $grupo);

    $resultados[] = $resultado;

}
// Que comando deveria usar para ter uma prévia dos resultados e verificar se está tudo ok?
print_r($resultado);
```

Comment: Nunca usei esse `XPath`, mas pelo que vejo, você não declarou a variavel `$resultado` e acho que você queria mostrar a `$resultados`, não a `$resultado`.

Comment: @Francisco. Declarei aqui `$resultados[] = $resultado;`

Comment: Não, não declarou.

Comment: A pergunta foi respondida em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759935/domxpath-and-foreach-how-to-get-a-preview-of-the-captured-elements/46760971#46760971